# Teams Connector: How to restrict visibility of cards to certain users

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

My requirement is that only certain people should see [cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/card-reference)/activities created by a [Teams Connector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors). Can this be done?

**Details:**

I played around with Teams Connectors and added some to a channel. It seems like the activities generated by the connectors I chose can be seen by the whole Team.

How can the sender of the activity (the system I'm connecting to) specify that an activity should only be visible to either

1. only the user that added the connector (kind of a "personal" connector)
2. a defined *set of users*, which is a subset of the members of the team

Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, at least not built in. Connectors simply render the cards based on the your app provided. The assumption here being that the owner of the Group/Team (who setup the Connector) is responsible for ensuring members of that Group/Team are valid recipients of the notification.

You could however add some intelligence to what data you provide back to the Team or Group. You could use [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) to pull a list of Group/Team members ([/groups/{id}/members](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members)) and use this to determine what level of data detail you should return. Note that this wouldn't prevent folks added later from seeing previous notifications, it would only effect what data they see going forward.

I would highly recommending visiting the [UserVoice](https://aka.ms/microsoftteamsplatformsuggestions) and adding your suggestions (and voting up others).